# Gearman Task Completion Callback

Tags: php, gearman

It's possible to set a callback when a single task has finished with `setCompleteCallback()` - is it possible to set a callback when an entire batch of tasks has completed (when run in parallel), for example if you use `runTasks()` as follows:

```
$client->addTask($method1, $data);
$client->addTask($method2, $data);
$client->runTasks();
```

I need to know when both tasks have been completed in order to close the job...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, `addTask` is synchronous so I don't need to do any polling, `runTasks` returns true once all have been completed so there's my answer.